# What should we do about the [user-list] tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta, burninate-request

The tag [user-list](/questions/tagged/user-list) has no tag wiki or excerpt.  It has just 12 questions.  It appears to be used only for talking about the [/users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) page on each site, and there is already a more concise tag for that:  [users-page](/questions/tagged/users-page).  Should we burn it?

Answer (score 5):

#### We should make it a synonym of [users-page](/questions/tagged/users-page)

As you note, they refer to the same page, but having them both be usable when tagging questions provides a convenient, intuitive synonym for anyone trying to tag a question relating to "the user list" that will result in the correct [users-page](/questions/tagged/users-page) tag being applied when they do so.

Comment: Hmm... yeah, I thought about suggesting a synonym, but went with the more nuclear option because they are pretty similar (and one is unambiguous).  You have to type `user-` to get the [tag:user-list] to come up, whereas you only need `users` for the correct tag... I see the sense in a synonym, but also a burnination.

Comment: My theory is that someone might type `user`, not see it, then go on to `user-` hoping to narrow it down.

Comment: Possibly.  But it's a list for all the user*s.*